Platform Events a nightmare - How to make them work in real life
I am trying to build a Platform Event-based application logger where arbitrary application code calls Tracker.log(...); and this is sent as an Event into an external database via an API. As it's important that

Events are sent even if the transaction fails
The tracking itself should merely never interfere with the app code
Tracking should not share Governor limits with triggering transaction

I moved the actual EventBus.publish(...) to a separate Queueable and configured the event to Publish immediately.
But when there is a DML or Callout after the Tracker is called like this:
Tracker.log(...);
...
app.makeCallout();

it fails with:

Failed calling callout:XYZ :You have uncommitted work pending. Please
commit or rollback before calling out


Take a look at Nebula code, they use PEs + Publish Immediately extensively, it's the backbone of their architecture. If it were us,  sent as an Event into an external database via an API would be implemented via Nebula assuming no packaging/intel. property issues.

On the assumption that it is not the end of the world if the odd logger message gets lost (remember that PEs do not have guaranteed delivery), the approach I would take is to separate the platform event from the delivery to an external system along the lines of what I did in this example github repo, but:

Without using an actual "Command" object in the database (you don't want to commit data into the originating transaction as this may fail and roll back).
Using a Publish Immediately event that contains the logger message detail.

The main difference is that the event must contain all relevant detail directly and each must be specifically processed. Throwing away events isn't an option here (unlike in my demo that only uses the event as a means to initiate processing).
You can use infrastructure features, such as event and replay IDs to ensure that you don't try to process too many events into callouts in one call to the platform event subscriber trigger - or ensure that the queueable can hold the total data to process and can self-chain to address the logger details that could not be sent immediately.

Queueing an Queueable is effectively DML. You're inserting a record to have the platform do something AFTER your transaction COMMITS.
The COMMIT part is important -- if your transaction fails (you hit a LimitException or SystemException), the entire transaction is rolled back, including the queued Queueable.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

If an Apex transaction rolls back, any queueable jobs queued for execution by the transaction aren’t processed.

Instead, you definitely want to call EventBus.publish() in your outer transaction (and have your PE set to Publish Immediately) so that it doesn't get rolled back regardless of the outer transaction outcome.
Regarding your concern about affecting the runtime characteristics of the application code. You need to be cognizant of the PE daily limit within the org -- for this reason, most log frameworks have configuration to flick the logging levels up or down to tune it to the specific use case (i.e. continuous logging of coarse application usage vs. trace level logging for debugging a specific scenario).
Implementing the configuration of the log level will also add some amount of overhead to the transaction.
In short, you won't get logging without some performance impact. The penalty should be minor but your definition of minor might vary from someone else's definition.

I moved the EventBus.publish to Queueable just because I already had "Uncommitted.." errors before when I called it directly. Could this instead be caused by a PE Trigger sending the Events to an API via Callout? How to solve that?

Is it not the case that Publish Immediately publication behaviour side-steps the mixed DML, since in this case the event doesn't go into the transaction but instead goes directly to the PE queue, I believe.

The PE limit is per hour, not per day, unless you are talking about cometD/pub-sub type subscribers. See the docs.

(Readying the question again, it seems my understanding of Publish Immediately vs mixed DML is wrong?)

This Release Note says that they relaxed the restriction on Publish before Callout in Summer '21 so it sounds like the behavior Robert is describing is unexpected. Maybe a Case with Support is required? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_publish_immediate_limit.htm&release=228&type=5
